# Does anyone use SubSonic in .Net

Tags: asp.net, orm, subsonic3, many-to-many, one-to-many

in SubSonic 3, if i use SimpleRepository,

can i ask it to generate forkey as well
include "one to many", "one to one" and "many to many"

is there any sample code i can have a look at????

what i see from its demo, is only for one table, not dealing with relationship

..if it cannot deal with relationship...i won`t go into it and use it then...

Answer (score 1):

I think a good place to get an understanding might be for you to take a listen to HanselMinutes.  [Here](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=150) is the episode with the creator of SubSonic.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the new Linq features built into subsonic 3. It should give you all you need for those types of joins.

[Example](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Linq_Select_Queries)

Otherwise you could use the [Simple Query Tool.](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Query_Tool)

Comment: hmm..the sample there...shows how to do relation query..

but what i means is that....when i create my model in in my C# code...such as classroom and student... one classroom maybe hold none, one or many student..when i finish my code, and put them into subSonic simple repository, i expect subsonic to create foreign key for me between those two table....can subsonic do that??

Comment: I heard it even doesn't support references fields. I can hardly imagine writing LINQ queries without it...